# How do you output the \ symbol using cout?

Tags: c++

How do you output \ symbol using cout?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use two backslashes `\\`

Answer (score 24):

In addition to all the correct answers, see this for further escaped characters

```
\a  Bell (beep)
\b  Backspace
\f  Formfeed
\n  Newline
\r  Return
\t  Tab
\\  Backslash
\'  Single quote
\"  Double quote
\xdd    Hexadecimal representation
\ddd    Octal representation
\?  Question mark ('?')
```

Comment: You missed a few. Also what happens with '\m' (ie a non special character).

Answer (score 16):

The '\' character is an escape character in C and C++.  You can output a literal '\' by escaping it with itself:

```
   cout << "This is a backslash: \\";
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
cout << "\\";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
std::cout << '\\';
```

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11 you can also use [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019).

```
std::cout << R"(There is no need to escape backslash here \)";
```

Escape characters (like \n \t or " ) are not processed in the raw string literals.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "\\" << endl;
```

Instead of endl you could:

```
cout << "\\ \n";
```