# I am trying draw a man in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
  cout<<"  O"<<endl;\\print    O
  cout<<"/ || \<<endl;\\print /||\
  cout<< "/  \" <<endl;\\print / \
  return 0;}
```

I am to print a standing man in console out that are upper given .but when I am compile it it give me error like (missing terminator character). If anyone know about it then tell me the correct solution of this program .I am waiting for your response...

Comment: The colors of the code on the snippet above means something :D

Comment: Comments in C++ are `//` not  \\ and `\"` is an escaped sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` has special meaning, it starts an [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Your code should be

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{  
  std::cout << "  O" << std::endl;     // print   O
  std::cout << "/ || \\" << std::endl; // print / || \ . some extra character to avoid final backslash in comment
  std::cout << " /  \\" << std::endl;  // print  /  \ . same here
  return 0;
}
```

or with raw string

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{  
  std::cout << R"(  O)" << std::endl;    // print   O
  std::cout << R"(/ || \)" << std::endl; // print / || \ . some extra character to avoid final backslash in comment
  std::cout << R"( /  \)" << std::endl;  // print  /  \ . same here
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you miss `"` on the second `cout`.
and look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650981/how-do-you-output-the-symbol-using-cout)

Answer (score 1):

With the C++11 and forward, you can use [raw strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  cout <<
      R"(
        O
       /||\
       /  \ )"

       << '\n';
}
```